# Filter an array for a subset of object keys

Tags: javascript, grep

Suppose I have:

```
var JSONArray = [{'key1':'a1','key2':'a2','key3':'a3'},
                 {'key1':'b1','key2':'b2','key3':'b3'},
                 etc 
                ];
```

How do I get an array that will hold the same objects, but without `'key3'`?

Comment: This a *JavaScript array* of *JavaScript objects*. It's not JSON and has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: You can't have an object with is the **same** as another object, but without some property. Then it will be another object, which may be **similar** to the first one, but you must define what similar means (e.g. same own properties, same own properties and same [[Prototype]], the [[Prototype]] of one is the other one, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) might be useful.

> Underscore is a JavaScript library that provides a whole mess of useful functional programming helpers without extending any built-in objects.

```
var JSONArray = [
    {'key1':'a1','key2':'a2','key3':'a3'},
    {'key1':'b1','key2':'b2','key3':'b3'}
];

_.map(JSONArray, function (x) { return _.omit(x, 'key3') });
=> [{'key1':'a1','key2':'a2'}, {'key1':'b1','key2':'b2'}]
```

Working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/1k9ryn01/)

Comment: For completeness, It would be nice to use _.reject in order to exclude 'key3' as Radu B requires.

Comment: My bad... Will change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the array and delete each key value pair where the key is `'key3'`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < JSONArray.length; i++) {
  delete JSONArray[i]['key3'];
}
```

JSONArray will now be:

```
[
  {key1: "a1", key2: "a2"},
  {key1: "b1", key2: "b2"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using map and reduce?

```
var JSONArray = [{'key1':'a1','key2':'a2','key3':'a3'},
                 {'key1':'b1','key2':'b2','key3':'b3'}
                ];

JSONArray.map(function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(filtered, curr){
    if(curr !== 'key3'){
      filtered[curr] = obj[curr];
    }
    return filtered;
  }, {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var JSONArray = [{'key1':'a1','key2':'a2','key3':'a3'},
                 {'key1':'b1','key2':'b2','key3':'b3'}];

1. You can remove the values from the objects in the array:

JSONArray.forEach(function(itm){
    delete itm.key3;
});


new value of JSONArray:    
[{"key1":"a1","key2":"a2"},{"key1":"b1","key2":"b2"}]


2. or you can clone a new array of new objects-

var nokey3= 
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSONArray));
nokey3.forEach(function(itm){
    delete itm.key3;
});


value of JSONArray:
[{"key1":"a1","key2":"a2","key3":"a3"},
{"key1":"b1","key2":"b2","key3":"b3"}]

value of nokey3:

[{"key1":"a1","key2":"a2"},{"key1":"b1","key2":"b2"}]
```